# Determining the equation of this 3D object

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

Does anyone know how I can determine the equation of the 3D object below? (Maybe there's a program that can do it?) I am looking for a formula to define this 3D object, but am having trouble finding one.

(If you can imagine the 2D object you see revolved about the x-axis, that is the 3D object I'm referring to.) Btw the z-axis can't be seen because the view of the object is head-on and the object is symmetrical with respect to the x-axis. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If the 2-d curve is to be revolved around the $x$ axis, and is symmetric with respect to it, then to specify the curve you only need some kind of formula in quadrant 1. You might want to restrict to such curves in which $y$ is a function of $x$, as it seems in your diagram, i.e. $y=g(x)$ for $0 \le x \le a$ [where $g(x)\ge 0$] Is this an OK way to state the format of the given curve?

Comment: Do you have an equation for the 2D curve in the $xy$ plane?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the top of the sketched curve has equation $y=f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le a$ and as in the diagram $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x$ in $[0,a].$ The distance from a 3-d point $(x,y,z)$ to the point $(x,0,0),$ in the plane having constant first coordinate $x,$ is $\sqrt{y^2+z^2},$ and in the revolved figure you want this distance to be $f(x).$

So an equation for the surface of the revolved curve is
$$\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=f(x),$$
or more simply, since $f(x) \ge 0,$ it can be written as
$$y^2+z^2=f(x)^2,$$
for $x$ satisfying $0 \le x \le a.$

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an object similiar to this of your figure, trace in spherical coordinates (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3D_Spherical_2.svg)
$$r = a\cdot sin(\phi)cos(\theta),$$ where $a$ is a positive constant, $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, and  $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi.$